# Software to convert XPS to PDF

Tags: windows, pdf, offline, document-converter, pdf-viewer

Most of the tools shown when searching for "[xps to pdf converter](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=xps%20to%20pdf%20converter)" are online. A few offline tools available require install and don't provide quality conversion. They seem to convert xps to image and then image to pdf.
I am looking for a free and portable *(optional)* xps converter for Windows that converts XPS to PDF preserving the text content wherever possible.

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/xpstopdf.1.html ?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I am using MS Windows.

Comment: [NovaPDF](http://www.novapdf.com) seems to be a good one, but it's free for trial only.

Comment: They also have [doPDF](http://dopdf.com) . It's free but large in size [40mb](http://download.dopdf.com/download/setup/dopdf-full.exe)

Comment: So my answer is no good for you, @Avi?

Comment: @KurtPfeifle I saw your answer only today. Thanks, a command-line tool will be handy at times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can open the XPS document then a pdf printer should work quite well.

I have often used [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator) for this exact task. If there is text in a document that it is printing it maintains that as a text format rather than text->image->pdf which truely does suck.

It is free and you can convert to many more formats as well. Some versions of the installer want to install semi-junk toolbars so make sure to unselect them unless for some bizarre reasons you do want them.

Comment: This brings us to the need for an app to open XPS. Can you complement the answer with this?

Answer (score 2):

**GhostPDL**, by the same developers as the better-known *Ghostscript* software, contains a module called **["GhostXPS"](http://www.ghostscript.com/GhostXPS.html)**.

You can **[download GhostXPS here](http://ghostscript.com/download/gxpsdnld.html)**. You can use it under the GPL as well as under a commercial license. There are pre-compiled binaries for Windows as well as Linux available (plus a source code license in order to self-compile it on other platforms, like Mac OS X).

To convert an XPS file to a PDF, use this command:

```
gxps -o out.pdf        \
     -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
      input.xps
```

Comment: @danicotra: This (v8.71) definitely is not a newer version of GhostXPS!

Comment: You're right, sorry, I definitely mistaken! Gonna change my comment and cross link the other answer too.

Comment: This is a good solution when you can't install a PDF printer. Linking to [another possible syntax to do the same thing using GhostXPS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8085558/1078556)