# XPS to PDF converter for Chromebook

Tags: document-converter, chrome-os, documentation-viewer

I have a large number of documents (over 1,000) in XPS format to which I need access from a Chromebook.
Rather than trying to find a PC and batch converting them to PDF, It would be much more convenient to either open them directly on the Chromebook or convert them to another supported format on the Chromebook.

Suggestions for conversion that I have found so far, [such](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/9837/246)  [as](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10209/246)  [these](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1361/246) three amongst others, either require the XPS document to be opened or use a web service.

I have failed to find an XPS extension for the Chrome browser and trying to open the XPS files in apps such as Google Docs fails.